# Incell Editing in datatable for primefaces not sending edited values to event

Tags: datatable, primefaces, inline, inline-editing

I want a table with in-line editing option in datatable. I am able to write full code but when i am clicking on edit button, the value which i am getting from event object from server side is same as old. I am not getting new values.

how to get new values from event object.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" 
                var="osList" 
                 value="#{WLMPortalViewController.allOSInfo}" rowKey="#{osList.osName}" 
                          paginator="true" rows="5"
                            paginatorPosition="bottom"
                           editable="true" >
                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{WLMPortalDataController.saveOSData}"/>
                <p:column headerText="Options" >
                    <p:rowEditor  /> 
                </p:column>


             <p:column headerText="Version" >
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{osList.osVersion}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText id="inputosVer" required="true" requiredMessage="* Version can't Empty." value="#{osList.osVersion}" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
             </p:column> 

            </p:dataTable>
```

and my server side code look like this

```
public void saveOSData(RowEditEvent event){

    System.out.print(event.getObject());

}
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm facing similar problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [PrimeFaces 3.0.M3 Cell Editor does not update value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707377/primefaces-3-0-m3-cell-editor-does-not-update-value)